# nested AVPlayer fullscreen?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I have an AVPlayer that's inside collectionview cell, that's inside a UICollectionView, that's located inside a collectionview cell.

I wanted to animate the AVPlayers frame to fit the entire screen, essentially a full screen transition however because of the hierarchy I'm having trouble accessing the main collectionview keywindow...

This is the code I am using so far in an attempt to access the full screens bounds.

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
     let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: -(window.frame.origin.x), y: (window.frame.origin.y) / 2, width: (window.frame.width) / 2, height: (window.frame.height) / 2 ))


        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.playerView?.bounds = v.bounds
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { (completed) in

        })
```

What this currently does is mask playerView to the bounds of the nested collectionView in the cell. Which leads me to believe because of how the hierarchy is that method might not be feasible.

I was hoping that there would be some method like AVPlayer.fullscreen() or something because I know it is possible to get fullscreen video using AVPlayerControllers overlay view but I don't want the user to have to press a button to go fullscreen. I prefer my current method of just tapping the video.

Any suggesetions?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an `AVPlayerLayer` this layer is the one that is going to be added as a sublayer to the view you want.

In this case first you need to add a `UIView` to your `collectionViewCell` and add your `AVPlayerLayer` instance as a sublayer.

When the user tap on the cell you must first remove `AVPlayerLayer` from the cell and pass the reference to your Root view controller in there you can add a new UIView of the size of the entire screen and add the `AVPlayerLayer` as a sublayer of that view.

Keep in mind that if you have a navigation controller you should add that UIView as a subview of the navigation controller and if you have a tabBar you need to add it to the tabBar insted.

To return from "Full screen" mode you do the oposite.

Comment: Will I be able to animate the transition?

Comment: A better question is when you say remove the AVPlayerLayer from the cell, do you mean completely remove it from the cell and then create a new instance of it in the rootView. Because if I'm doing that how am I to access the former location of the AVPlayerLayer when I'm placing it in the root view. (if possible I want to animate it from it's former location to full screen and vice versa).